# How do i retrieve the full list of all auth/cipher pairs that an AP can accept?

Tags: winapi, wifi, wlanapi

The function `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList` provides a list of `WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK` structures containing, among other things, the default authentication algorithm and the default cipher for each network detected. However, access points can be configured to accept multiple combinations of authentication algorithms/ciphers, for example, an AP might be configured to support both WPA and WPA2 at the same time. Hence the question, how do i retrieve the full list of all auth/cipher pairs that an AP can accept?

I tried with `WlanGetNetworkBssList` but the `WLAN_BSS_ENTRY` structures that it outputs only have the `usCapabilityInformation` parameter that only tells me whether encryption is required or not via the `Privacy` bit.

Comment: Try to use [`WlanQueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanqueryinterface) + `wlan_intf_opcode_supported_infrastructure_auth_cipher_pairs`/`wlan_intf_opcode_supported_adhoc_auth_cipher_pairs` to query the [`WLAN_AUTH_CIPHER_PAIR_LIST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/ns-wlanapi-wlan_auth_cipher_pair_list).

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Afaik, that function is for retrieving info about the local interface, not the access points.

Comment: I will consult relevant engineers internally, any progress will be updated here.

Comment: Can you query such information in the network center without programming?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I don't know. I tried with command `netsh wlan show networks` but yet again it returns only one authentication algorithm for each AP.

Comment: If you cannot obtain this information manually, you may also not be able to obtain it programmatically. Could you please share your use case?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I am certain this is possible because inSSIDer can retrieve that info. I really have no clue how tho. I need that to automate diagnostics for a few APs i got that might be defective.